# Linux / Node.js Error de Require

Tags: linux

Obtive este erro quando corri o ficheiro "TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined"

```
 var Main = Electron.remote.require('./payment.js');
```

Onde poderei estar a errar?... Confuso...O suposto payment.js encontra-se na mesma pasta que este ficheiro.

Comment: então remova `./`....do path

Comment: Sem soluçao ainda....

Answer (score 0):

> Já tive exatamente o mesmo problema que você, e resolvi retirando o ' **./** ':

`var Main = Electron.remote.require('payment.js');`

Comment: não resultou, o problema é o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Silva\Desktop\Steam-Card-Farmer-master\Steam-Card-Farmer-master\farmer.js:10:42)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

este e o codigo

```
var SteamUser = require('steam-user');
var Steam = SteamUser.Steam;
var request = require('request');
var Cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require("fs");

var client = new SteamUser({"enablePicsCache": 
true,"promptSteamGuardCode":false});

var Electron = require('electron');
```

-->    var Main = Electron.remote.require('main.js');

```
var g_Jar = request.jar();
request = request.defaults({"jar": g_Jar});
var g_Page = 1;
var g_Start;
var g_CheckTimer;
var g_OwnedApps = [];
```